# How to trigger complete: method for a NSTextFieldCell, in order to display the autocomplete list?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I use `NSTextView` is easy to trigger the autocomplete popup with the list of suggestions, with the method `complete:` or by pressing F5.

I'm trying to have the same with a `NSTextFieldCell`. F5 works very well, but I don't have the method `complete:` and therefore I can't open such menu programmatically. How to solve it ?

This is what I've tried:

1. implement the NSTextField delegate method `textShouldBeginEditing`: but such method is only invoked after a key is pressed and not when the cell gets focus
2. override `becomeFirstResponder` in a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell` but such method is never invoked. And in any case, even if it was, I wouldn't know how to implement it, since, as I said before, the complete: method is not part of the cell APIs.
3. implement

   ```
   - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
   ```

   but such method is invoked *before* the cell enters in edit mode, and again, I wouldn't know what to do as in point 2.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

Subclass the `NSTextFieldCell` and override this method to customize its `NSTextView`

```
- (NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)aControlView
{
    return [[[CBAutocompleteTextField alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Subclass the `NSTextView` (`CBAutocompleteTextField` in my case) and add this to trigger the autocomplete when it gets focus:

```
-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(complete:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but the cell's focus ring no longer matches the focus ring used by the non-subclassed fields.